# Add/change optional parameters (matrix notation) in url without navigating

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I know how to navigate adding additional parameters to a router, e.g:

```
this._router.navigate(['/users', { page: 2 }]);
```

Will result in navigation to `/users;page=2`.

What I'd like to do though, is to be able to modify these parameters without actually navigating. Just change the URL to update/add parameters.

This can be useful for example when displaying a table and the user changes the sort key or adds a filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `router.navigate()` method. The router will recognize that you're asking to navigate to the same component, so it will change the parameters without actually navigating away.

To be notified of the new parameter and update the UI, you subscribe to the `ActivatedRoute.params` Observable:

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     let page = +params['page']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
     let sort = params['sort'] || 'ASC'; //use ASC order if none is supplied
     this.updateUI(page,sort);//function would update component as you wish
   });
}
```

Search for *params.subscribe* [on this page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) for more info.

Comment: That's how I'm doing it already, I just thought the component was being reloaded each time. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AArias If you put a `console.log('New construction')` in the constructor, or at the top of `ngOnInit`, you should notice that it gets called only once even as you navigate to the same route. There was a bug that prevented this behavior for lazy routes in RC 5, but it should have been fixed with RC 6 (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10841)

Comment: Converting to a number with `Number(params['page'])` would be more clear to anyone reading the code.